# Database connect not successful TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I am working for the first time on one hosting with TYPO3, and seems that I can't connect to database during initial setup (first install). My username and passwords are **correct**, **and I can access to database using other methods** but i simply can't with TYPO3 install tool. I tried with default hosts (e.g. localhost and default 127.0.0.1) and even socket based connection but nothing.

Any help please?

Best regrads

Comment: Which TYPO3 version is being used and which "other methods" connecting to the database worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my local development machine. The solution for me was to comment out the `skip-networking` line in the MySQL server configuration file `my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

At first localhost or 127.0.0.1 will be successful as long as the mysql server is located on the same server.

Either you can create an special typo user for the server and bind it to an DB or you can use the default root user. Any other user also migth work depending on the configuration. Here you should check the accessrigths for the user u want TYPO to log in as.

For the password section you have to check if the user needs a password. If not just omit it.

**Also try to select an empty but existing database**

The connection type is not really relevant cause most of the problems are caused by wrong host,user, password, database settings.