# Installation tool of Typo3 (Version 9.5.5) cannot connect to MySql 8 database on MacOs Mojave

Tags: mysql, macos, typo3, typo3-9.x

I am installing a Typo3 CMS version 9.5.5 on a MacOs Mojave system using MySql database.

Details of environment:
MySql database :  Ver 8.0.16 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (installed with Homebrew)
OS: MacOs Mojave 10.14.4
Typo 3 Version: 9.5.5

Installation gets error in second step when trying to establish a connection against the database:
"Database connect not successful
Connecting to the database with given settings failed: An exception occurred in driver: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

1) I verified the user/password combination by using the mysql shell command
mysql -u  -p  and I can successfully connect to Mysql

2) I did installation step 2 using TCP/IP connection and also MySql socket connection modes, but error message is same on both modes

3) As recommended by [Database connect not successful TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044538/database-connect-not-successful-typo3) I did set the skip-networking option in /usr/local/ etc/my.cnf to 0 but this did not help.

4) Current configured database connectivity in Typo3 LocalConfiguration file is using the following settings

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'driver' => 'mysqli',
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'password' => '***',
'port' => 3306,
'tableoptions' => [
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collate' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
],
'user' => 'root',
],
],
```

I expect to pass step 2 in Typo3 installation with successful connectivity to MySql database but get error message see above.

Comment: Are your credentials configured in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] or LocalConfiguration under ['DB']['Connections']['Default'] ?

Comment: The credentials are configured under  ['DB']['Connections']['Default']. But as Thomas Löffer mentioned in his answer, I violate the system requirements and I cannot connect to MySql version 8.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Christian,

TYPO3 v9 does not support MySQL v8, see: https://get.typo3.org/version/9#system-requirements

The thing is: You want a local setup that mirrors the server TYPO3 should run later, shouldn't it?

I would suggest to use an environment that is similar to the later webserver. And the current servers support mostly MySQL 5.6 or 5.7, also MariaDB 10 is an option.

Look at a virtual machine like Docker or Vagrant to build your TYPO3 website.
Maybe this can help: [What's the fastest way to install and set up TYPO3 locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949302/whats-the-fastest-way-to-install-and-set-up-typo3-locally)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should have a closer look to the system requirements section. I will use MySql 5.7 locally on my development environment.

Answer (score 1):

**TYPO3 v9 does not support MySQL v8**

I can confirm this. With TYPO3 version 10 it works finally!
But unfortunately there are still some other issues with version 10.